# How do I reset the App Layout in vaadin 14?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using the App Layout component in vaadin 14 and I set up the `/admin` route as my default view. I set up a Tabs component to switch the main areas content for those views. It works really well, however, I have no clue how to reset the `/admin` route to its initial state. I tried setting up an Anchor to go to "/admin" but it refreshes the page.

**MainView**

```java
@Route("admin")
public class MainView extends AppLayout {

  @Autowired
  public MainView() {
    setPrimarySection(AppLayout.Section.DRAWER);
    addToDrawer(createMenuTabs());
    setContent(customView);
  }

  private static Tabs createMenuTabs() {
    final Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
    tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
    tabs.add(getAvailableTabs());
    return tabs;
  }

  private static Tab[] getAvailableTabs() {
    final List<Tab> tabs = new ArrayList<>(2);
    tabs.add(createTab(VaadinIcon.HOME, "Home", CustomView.class));
    tabs.add(createTab(VaadinIcon.EDIT, "Events", EventsView.class));

    return tabs.toArray(new Tab[tabs.size()]);
  }

  private static Tab createTab(VaadinIcon icon, String title,
      Class<? extends Component> viewClass) {
    return createTab(populateLink(new RouterLink(null, viewClass), icon, title));
  }

  private static Tab createTab(Component content) {
    final Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.add(content);
    return tab;
  }

  private static <T extends HasComponents> T populateLink(T a, VaadinIcon icon, String title) {
    a.add(icon.create());
    a.add(title);
    return a;
  }
}
```

The only way that I have made it work is by adding a route to the custom view.

**CustomView**

```java
@Route(value = "admin/home", layout = MainView.class)
public class CustomView extends VerticalLayout...
```

but this changes the url to `.../admin/home`.

I simply want to go back to `/admin` without a refresh. I hope I'm just missing something simple in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by giving my MainView a `@RoutePrefix("admin")` instead of `@Route` and then in my "home" view the `@Route("")` route. This way doesn't reload or reset the app but just gets back to the home URL without a refresh.